Would a "plug and play" prosthetic be possible?
A plug and play prosthetic is a type of prosthetic that does not require months of rehabilitation just to use, rather, this type of prosthetic can be used immediately after it is surgically installed, is this type of implant possible, and if so, what technology/method would be used? (I apologize if my question writing skills are subpar, i am both autistic and new to this platform)

What sort of implant/prosthetic? Eye lens-implants seem to work fine, same with hearing-aids. Can you edit to be specific about what you need. Do you mean something more like a replacement arm/leg. Similarly, our current prosthetics fit what you've asked and do work first time. Anything would take some getting used to except a direct replacement for another prosthetic. So what functionality are you looking for over what time?

For future reference, please provide the intended technological level for questions like this. Nosajimiki's answer is true today, but it needn't be true in the future. Frankly, the idea of a prosthetic that comes with "drivers" (akin to those needed by any computer peripheral) that interface with the brain (which might require a cybernetic implant to permit this) to automatically code the brain for the prosthetic is uber-cool and frankly believable. And the concept has already been touched on from The Matrix to Clarke's 2061: Odyssey Three.

Oh, one more thing. Think through your use of [tag:science-fiction], [tag:science-based] and [tag:hard-science]. From a [tag:science-based] perspective Nosajimiki's and Robert's answers are false. Science today does not understand the brain well enough to permit this at all. Remember Clarke's second law, "The only way of discovering the limits of the possible is to venture a little way past them into the impossible.." They did you a favor by answering in terms of [tag:science-fiction].

We can help you with your question writing skills! JBH and Escaped Dental Patient make some valid points which may or may not invalidate potential answers. A good place to hone your question writing skills is right in our very own Sandbox! There's no need to apologise, though I get where you're coming from. The Sandbox is just an awesome place to learn the craft!

well you are right, i didnt really know science based was for modern-esque stuff, should have put hard sci-fi

also how do i close a question

Yes and No
Every brain and nervous system is different.  Which means the only way to make a neurologically controlled robotic prosthetic work is to train it to you nervous system.  But... this assumes that the prosthetic is your first.  If you had some kind of neurological interface installed before you needed the new limb, it could map out your biometrics, so that way, when you need the new prosthetic, a biometric map already exists for you and your new limb could just interface with the device that already knows how you think.

Or in other words, it's not about the implementation, it's about the interface. If the interface is already there, and the new implementation conforms, then using the new implementation requires little to no adaptation. For every deviation, a bit more adaptation is required.

@MatthieuM. Yes, it does depend on what the original interface is and what it's designed to map.  If you for example have a neurojack that you use to map brain patterns to character movements in Call of Duty 42, then it stands to reason that your entire motor cortex is already fully mapped and indexed, but if you just use it for making virtual sculpture, your legs may not be mapped out and ready to replace.

The other answers bring up the issues of adaptability.  Human nerves grow organically and somewhat randomly.
Perfect Tech 1
If you wanted to have a perfect implant that mimicked the original you could dissolve the limbs around the nerves and reattach the nerves to the proper circuits and assuming you matched sizes and weights it should be flawless.
None of that is ever going to happen, since replacement limbs are often the result of catastrophic removal. (This might be an option for bone cancer, but in that case why not substitute just the bone)
Tech Available Soonish
To make a ready to go replacement you would have to match severed nerves to their function and none of them are labeled.  With tech in sight of ours now you could attach a micro wire to each nerve at the sever and then see what sense each carries to a similarly wired up brain and likewise stimulate section of the motor cortex to see which muscles get triggered.  The cerebellum might also need to be mapped since that serves a multiplexer.
This would likely only be an 80/20 solution.  It would be awkward and glitchy but walking on day 1 or simple grasping tasks on day 1 would be possible.
The Real Issue
Healing.  Skin takes days to heal up.  Weeks before it is something durable to bear loads.  Underlying tissue starts off swollen after the initial injury and then atrophies.  The muscles in the calf which work the ankles and toes no longer connect to anything and will shrink.  One of the reasons therapy and revisions are needed for prosthesis is that the body changes to adapt.  There are a lot of things interconnected.
Growing a new one
The solution to prosthesis might just be to "deadpool" a new one.  Daily injections of stem cells and growth factors and a few weeks a new foot could be yours.

It's vaguely possible, but it would require a mapping of the individual's neurology before implantation. They do that post-implantation with low-res eye implants now, stimulating random nerves while the patient tells them what part of their field of vision lights up.
Being able to use it the moment you hop off of the operating table is another issue. Your bones have to grow into any structural implant. You would have to wait for the nerve endings to reduce swelling, and you'd have to deal with infections.
What you COULD do is implant a socket on the end of a stump and, when the socket finished healing, you'd then be able to attach various limbs onto it. This has been the case with prosthetic legs for some time, although that is a matter of fitting the prosthetic to the shape of the stump, so it's still not actually plug-and-play.
The thing in Fallout where they use a foot-o-matic to attach a prosthetic leg is pure fiction.

I'll take your question more literally.
Plug-and-Play could me more easily achieved if the body if first fitted with sockets for the artificial limbs to plug into. The sockets themselves would need a very complex surgery, long healing process and a long learn-to-use process.
But once that is done, any kind of prosthesis could be plugged in.
For example, it might take a difficult surgery and a year of healing to have a cybernetic eye socket installed and make it function well with your visual nerve. But once that is done, it would be relatively easy to plug different artificial eyeballs into it, depending on need, and each one would only need a few days of adjustment.
